# Can't Get Regex To Work in uBot - Extracting Phone Numbers

Tags: regex

Got a block of text I'm trying to pull phone numbers out of.

for example:

> Phone Numbers
>
> Any phone numbers that Angelo may currently or previously have used
>   are displayed below. Run a phone report on a particular number for
>   more information.
>
> (555) 444-5555 
> (555) 555-7777
>  Not seeing something? Access additional
>   data sources. Accessing premium data sources may reveal hard to find
>   phone numbers like cell phones

the regex code I wrote to extract the numbers is

> .?\d{3}.?\s\d{3}.\d{4}

For whatever reason, the results turn back blank and I'm not sure why. I've tested this regex code inside a uBot Expresion Checker and it pulls the phone numbers out as it should. But once I enter it in uBot it pulls nothing.

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

FIGURED IT OUT:

> .*\d3.?\s\d{3,5}.\d{3,5}

for whatever reason uBot wouldn't display the phone numbers correctly until I had the above worked out.

Comment: Maybe `.*([(]\d{3}[)]\s\d{3}-\d{4})` will work better?